# How can I combine a heroku-rails backend with an android application?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, backend

I am new to webdev and was wondering how I can retrieve data from a heroku backed rails application. All post requests would be from a web browser and the android app would only ever need to retrieve(query) data from the database. Also, there is no login/user system on the android app; app users can just view specific information from the database. I'm new to backend development and it would be nice to have a set of resources which can help me understand what I need to know and an overall approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you need is to provide an API in your rails application. There's a lot of resources but I'll suggest to start with [rails api screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/348-the-rails-api-gem). Althoug it's meant for an API only application.

If you want to add and API to an existant full rails app, check [this blog post](http://railsware.com/blog/2013/04/08/api-with-ruby-on-rails-useful-tricks/) which covers the essencials on a Rails API, including tips for speedup.

For securing your API there's also a screencast on the subject: [#352 Securing an API](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api)

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at the screen cast. What do I do to ensure only the app has access to the database as app users only see what the app queries/shows them?

Comment: @OreAsonibare I've updated the answer to match the security.